# Drools: Test/Validating Unique LHS in Rules

Tags: drools

Is it possible to test if a set of rules's conditions overlap?  A simplified version of my current problem is, if I have a set of rules which tests Person.age, is it possible to guarantee/validate/test the LHS is only valid for at most one rule?

For example, these two rules are "valid":

```
rule "r1"
when
  Person( age > 0 && age < 18 )
then
  // do something
end

rule "r2"
when
  Person( age >= 18 && age < 65 )
then
 // do something else
end
```

But the following is not:

```
rule "r1"
when
  Person( age > 0 && age < 10 )
then
  // do something
end

rule "r2"
when
  Person( age >= 8 && age < 16 )  // range overlaps with r1!
then
 // do something else
end
```

I'm aware I can use halt() to prevent multiple rules from firing, I'm looking for ways to prevent, or at least warn of, the possibility of multiple rules firing.

Answer (score 2):

An overlap like this isn't necessarily a bug in the rules, so you'll have to write some code of your own, checking what is wrong according to your setup.

The "Stable API" does not provide a way to access compiled rules to retrieve constraints. You would have to use some internal API classes. Writing this code and testing (!) it is likely to be more effort than the development of solid tests for your rules - which you'd have to do anyway.

Warning against more than one rule firing out of a set of rules could be done in a straightforward way by an event listener.

Answer (score 1):

I can't imagine that there is a way that drools "auto-detects" if there is a rule overlap, so like laune said in his answer you'll have to come up with your own test cases etc and use event listeners for alerting multiple rules.

In order to prevent a second/third/etc rule from firing you could insert control facts that are shared among all rules (similar to e.g. https://ilesteban.wordpress.com/2012/11/16/about-drools-and-infinite-execution-loops/)
But they would be then part of your rule conditions.
So you'd end up adding a condition like

```
not RuleHasFiredControlFact
```

to your LHS and something like

```
insert(new RuleHasFiredControlFact())
```

to your RHS (pseudo code, not complete)